# JDOI variance reduction method python

Tags: american-options, variance

Has anyone read the paper 'JDOI variance reduction method and the pricing of
American-style options' by Johan. I want to implement the simulation. But For Monte carlo I got different results.  andI don't know how to do JDOI in python.
https://doi.org/10.1080/14697688.2021.1962959

here is my code
`# define standard monte carlo function

def BlackScholesMC(S0, K, sigma, r, T, n_steps, n_paths):

```
dt = T / n_steps  # length of time steps
option_prices = []
for _ in range(n_paths):  
    w = np.random.standard_normal((n_steps,n_paths))
    ST = S0 * np.exp(np.cumsum((r - 0.5 * sigma**2) * dt - sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * w))
    payoff = K - ST
    payoff = payoff * (payoff > 0)
    option_prices.append(payoff)
MC = np.exp(-r * dt) * np.mean(option_prices)
MCstd=np.exp(-r*dt)*np.std(payoff)/np.sqrt(n_paths)
return MC, MCstd
```

print(ST.shape)

## Parameters for the simulation

S0 = 100      # Initial stock price
K = 100       # Strike price
T = 0.5       # Time to maturity in years
r = 0.04      # Risk-free interest rate
sigma = 0.25   # Volatility of the underlying asset
n_paths = 200 # Number of sample paths per run
n_steps = 100 # Number of time steps

## Running the simulation 200 times and collecting the results

n_runs = 200  # Number of runs

all_MC_estimates = []  # To collect the MC estimates from each run

for _ in range(n_runs):
MC_estimate, MC_std = BlackScholesMC(S0, K, sigma, r, T, n_steps, n_paths)
all_MC_estimates.append(MC_estimate)

## Plotting the distribution of the option prices

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.hist(prices, bins=30, alpha=0.75, edgecolor = 'black')
plt.title('Monte Carlo estimates, European Put')
plt.xlabel(' Option Price')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.